# How to block bad packets?

Tags: iptables

I want to block bad packets. I have used CSF and added them into csfpost.sh...
But I really to block these
(Flags: SYN ECN CWR)

right now, These are my rules..

```
#!/bin/bash
# Drop Various Attacks
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8080 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ECN,CWR -j DROP

# Prevent source address 127.0.0.1 from sending data through various interfaces
iptables -A INPUT -p all -s localhost -i wlan0 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p all -s localhost -i eth0 -j DROP

# Drop Fragments
iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP

# Drop ICMP (Ping) Packets
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP

# Do not respond to pings
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP

# Drop Invalid Packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Drop LAND (Local Area Network Denial) Packets
# In this attack, a packet is spoofed to make the source address appear as the IP-address of the target.  In other words, the source and destination IP-addresses are the same.
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP

# Drop Null Packets
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Drop excessive RST Packets to avoid Smurf-Attacks
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT

## Drop Smurf-Attacks
# Smurf-Attacks send a large number of ICMP "echo broadcast" packets with a spoofed source IP-address being the target's IP-address. The machines on the network recieve this broadcast message and reply to the target with "echo reply" packets. One way to block this attack is to block all the ICMP packets. However, if that cannot be done, then a limit may be applied to the ICMP packets allowed.
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type address-mask-request -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP

# Drop Spank DoS Attacks
# Computers answer TCP packets that are coming from a multicast-address. This can be used for the Spank DoS Attack or stealth-scans.
iptables -A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 239.255.255.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j DROP

# Drop SYN Flood Packets
# This is a type of DOS (Denial Of Service) attack.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Drop XMAS Packets
# A Christmas-Tree Packet is a packet that has all flags of any protocol set. The FIN, URG, and PSH bits in the TCP header are set. This packet is called an "Xmas Tree" packet because all the fields of header are "lightened up".
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Prevent Port-scans

# Use only one of the two given port-scan lock-out systems
# Lock-out systems that attempted a port-scan (lock lasts a day)
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --remove
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --remove
# Lock-out systems that attempted a port-scan (lock lasts a week)
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 604800 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --rcheck --seconds 604800 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --remove
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --remove

# Log Port-Scan Attempts
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --set -j LOG --log-prefix "Portscan:"
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name portscan --set -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --set -j LOG --log-prefix "Portscan:"
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name portscan --set -j DROP

# Block Packets used by Port-Scans
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL URG,PSH,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL URG,PSH,SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 4):

Trying to [list and drop all the possible bad things](https://www.ranum.com/security/computer_security/editorials/dumb/) is futile, since that list may be infinite and certainly keeps expanding. Instead, the recommended principle in designing firewall rules is to define rules to accept the kinds of traffic that is **necessary** for the system to do its job, and then add one final rule to **drop everything else.**

If your "CSF" is [ConfigServer Firewall,](https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) then it most likely is already designed with this principle.

You said your rules are in `csfpost.sh` and they all seem to be `iptables -A` commands, so they add new rules at the end of the rule chains created by CSF. But if CSF is well-designed, it places a "drop everything that has not been already accepted" rule at the end of its rules. Since rules are checked in order, your long list of manual rules might actually have **no actual effect at all,** since they are all added after the last CSF rule.

Your script also includes some rules that might be actually harmful if they were actually placed in the beginning of the ruleset. For example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
```

You're blocking all outgoing UDP traffic. IP multicast can only use IGMP for control and UDP for data. These rules would mean the system cannot send any useful IPv4 nor IPv6 multicast messages at all. Since IPv6 essentially replaces broadcast with multicast, this would effectively cripple IPv6. On the IPv4 side, this would block the most basic DNS queries, NTP, and DHCP.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Since this rule is not restricted to external interfaces, it would take effect for the loopback interface too, and would effectively drop all traffic on it. Blocking the loopback interface will cause a lot of software to not work or behave very strangely.

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
...
iptables -A INPUT -d 239.255.255.0/24 -j DROP
```

This will also drop all IPv4 multicasts. The second rule is unnecessary since the first one already covers it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j DROP
```

If your system acts as a DHCP server, this will break that functionality. (A DHCP client does not yet know its IP address when it starts up, and so it can only send broadcasts with source address 0.0.0.0 and destination address 255.255.255.255. If such broadcasts are passed as-is from one network segment to another by a router, that router is badly misconfigured.)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Only 2 new incoming TCP connections per second, with a buffer of 2 more connections? A single web browser can easily saturate that.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ECN,CWR -j DROP
```

[ECN is not a single flag, but a technique involving multiple new TCP flags.](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2015/10/30/tcp-flags-cwr-ece/) The Linux kernel already supports ECN. It probably already has built-in sanity checks that are more accurate than what you can do with simple iptables rules.

```
iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP
```

Dropping IP fragments is probably obsolete advice: the Linux kernel can and will automatically re-assemble and sanity-check all fragments as needed anyway. This happens before packets are handled by `iptables` connection tracking, so it is likely this rule may never match anything.

Overall, it seems to me that you're either gathering up various firewall rules without completely understanding what they mean, or following outdated or incomplete advice.

To design effective firewall rules at the level of individual `iptables` commands, you really need to know all the types of network traffic the system needs to accept to do its job, and have at least a basic understanding of the protocols involved. If you try to collect rules for each possible bad thing without understanding their relations to the "good" types of traffic, you'll always fail. If you proceed on this path, you'll learn this the hard way - consider yourself warned.

Comment: Thank you for such kind and good explanation. I really have very less knowledge in iptables.

Comment: May You provide me some basic rules so I can add them on csfpre.sh

Comment: You really should first try to understand the rules CST already provides for you, so you don't needlessly create duplicate rules. Then, if you need help in creating more firewall rules, *please describe in detail what the system is supposed to do.* Are you using static IP addresses or DHCP? Are you using IPv6? Is this a workstation/laptop or a server? What services does it need to provide to other systems? Does it need to run a web browser? Do you want the system to be able to download updates from the internet?

Comment: That link of 'dumb ideas' is ..dumb. At leats some of them. Educating users is important. The fact not everyone is educated doesn't mean it hasn't helped. It has helped. Also it's a game of cat and mouse. So too is the idea of patching: it's important. The idea that if something shouldn't be crackable should never be designed to be is ignoring reality: any programmer worth their salt knows that bugs happen. I know this very well. Bugs abound in software. There are some other flaws in the essay. Default accept of course is bad. AV don't only do 'enumerating bad' either: they do more than that.